# Prove that for any $n \ge 3$, $a(n) = 2a(n − 1) + 2a(n − 2)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Considering $a(n)$: the number of sequences of the form $(s_1,s_2,...,s_n)$ where $s_i$ can be 0,1 or 2 without consecutive 0's (like 1,0,0). (e.g. $a(1) = 3^1 = 3$, $a(2)= 3^3-1=8$, etc.)

I have to prove (by direct proof) that for any $n \ge 3$, $a(n) = 2a(n − 1) + 2a(n − 2)$. The hint suggests to work by cases (not by enumerating every case, but by subdividing them in categories)

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This is obvious if we use a generating function.

Answer (score 0):

$a(n)$ is the sum of all allowed sequences starting with 0 and all allowed sequences starting with 1 or 2. In the first case, you have 2 options for the second term of the sequence (since it can't be zero) and the remaining of the sequence can be chosen in $a(n-2)$ ways. In the second case, you have 2 options for the first entry of the sequence and $a(n-1)$ ways to chose the rest.